# Where is the difference in Angular for error handling in a component and service?

Tags: angular, service, error-handling

```
this.apiService.getUser().subscribe(result => {
  // do something with the result
}, error => {
if (error.status == 400) {
  this.errorMessage = "Invalid request paramater.";
} else if (error.status == 403) {
  this.errorMessage = "Insufficient priviliges for executing this method.";
} else {
  this.errorMessage = "Unknown error";
}
// view the error message with a toast
});
```

This code-snippet is from a method in a service of my webapp. 
If an error occurs, for example the error status 403, then I get an error in the console of my browser and the app block all buttons in the webapp. But if I export this code-snippet in a method of a component, then there doesn’t occur errors anymore.
My question is, why I can catch/handle erros only in a component and not in a Service?

Note: the apiService.getUser do only an request like: this.http.get(uri, headers, params, null);

```
public getUser(): Observable<HttpResponse<User>> {
  let uri = `/users/current`;
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  let params = new HttpParams();
  return this.sendRequest<User>('get', uri, headers, params, null);
}

private sendRequest<T>(method: string, uri: string, headers: HttpHeaders, params: HttpParams, body: any): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {
  if (method === 'get') {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.domain + uri, { headers: headers.set('Accept', 'application/json'), params: params, observe: 'response' });
}
```

Comment: Show your api service so we can help ya

Comment: @MikeTung I added my apiService methods